# Python Pandas inconsistent results with nested for each iteration

Tags: python, pandas

This is my first post and I apologise as I am struggling to make sense.

I am using Pandas with Python to do data analysis and have an issue that I dont understand (and so am struggling to explain).

I am calling a function from within a 'for each loop' which attempts to insert values into a Pandas DataFrame based on a specified column start and end location. The function is this:

```
cfg_broll_temp.ix[cfg_broll_temp['aged_debt'] == colb,scolb:ecolb] = tmp_brollb
```

And the error is the following:

```
ValueError: Must have equal len keys and valuewhen setting with an iterable
```

I have tracked this down to an iteration I am doing within the function that is being called. I am running through a for each loop based on an item list, and for each item running a nested for each to step through a slice of a Pandas series (cfg_broll_sr[srowb:erowb]) in order to generate a result list (tmp_brollb) which I update to the DataFrame with in the failing statement.

My issue is that despite the same starting conditions when I call this function it seems to generate a list of inconsistent length. e.g. with values of srowb = 1 and erowb = 18 it will generate a list (tmp_brollb) which has either len(tmp_brollb) = 17 or len(tmp_brollb) = 18

I am banging my head against a wall with this as I am struggling to isolate any changes that cause this.

The specific code block I am having issues with is:

```
# Set starting conditions

srowb = 1 # starting row
if np.isnan(variable) :
    erowb = 18 
else:
    erowb = int(variable)

# iterate through list
tmp_brollb = [] # Generate empty array
z = 0 # reset starting value
for itemr in cfg_broll_sr[srowb:erowb]:
    z = min(z + itemr,1) # prevent more that 100%
    tmp_brollb.append(z)

# Increment

srowb = srowb + 1
erowb = min(erowb + 1,20)
```

Some more detail on the code here:

```
# Set maximum number of rows and starting row
rowsb = 18
srowb = 1 # starting row

# check if a event exists and set maximum row to cease value
if np.isnan(event_month) :
    erowb = 18 
else:
    erowb = int(event_month) 

# Set starting conditions for range insertion 
basecolb = 7 # starting column for roll data
scolb = basecolb # Getting an expanding range of columns from 1 to 18
ecolb = basecolb + erowb

# item tuple for step through
dcolsb = ('item1','item2','item3')

# step through and update values
for colb in dcolsb :

    # Generate accumulated arrays
    tmp_brollb = None # clear variable
    tmp_brollb = [] # Generate empty array
    z = 0 # reset starting value
    for itemr in cfg_broll_sr[srowb:erowb]:
        z = min(z + itemr,1) # prevent more that 100%
        tmp_brollb.append(z)

    # insert accumulated values into selected row and column range
    cfg_broll_temp.ix[cfg_broll_temp['item_column'] == colb,scolb:ecolb] = tmp_brollb
    # carry last value from tmp_brollb forward to end of column range
    cfg_broll_temp.ix[cfg_broll_temp['item_column'] == colb,ecolb:] = tmp_brollb[-1]

    # increment all positional variables
    srowb = srowb + 1
    erowb = min(erowb + 1,20)
    scolb = scolb + 1
    ecolb = min(ecolb + 1,25)
```

If I print the following I get:

```
    print "inconsistent length issue", len(tmp_brollb), erowb - srowb, srowb, erowb


run strategy 17
inconsistent length issue 18 17 1 18 # len(tmp_brollb) inconsistent despite same erowb - srowb value
inconsistent length issue 17 17 2 19
inconsistent length issue 16 17 3 20
inconsistent length issue 15 16 4 20
inconsistent length issue 14 15 5 20
inconsistent length issue 13 14 6 20
inconsistent length issue 12 13 7 20
inconsistent length issue 11 12 8 20
inconsistent length issue 10 11 9 20
inconsistent length issue 9 10 10 20
inconsistent length issue 8 9 11 20
inconsistent length issue 7 8 12 20
inconsistent length issue 6 7 13 20
run strategy 17 again via parent iterator
inconsistent length issue 17 17 1 18 # len(tmp_brollb) inconsistent despite same erowb - srowb value
inconsistent length issue 17 17 2 19
inconsistent length issue 16 17 3 20
inconsistent length issue 15 16 4 20
inconsistent length issue 14 15 5 20
inconsistent length issue 13 14 6 20
inconsistent length issue 12 13 7 20
inconsistent length issue 11 12 8 20
inconsistent length issue 10 11 9 20
inconsistent length issue 9 10 10 20
inconsistent length issue 8 9 11 20
inconsistent length issue 7 8 12 20
inconsistent length issue 6 7 13 20
```

**Any help would be much appreciated as I have a 4hr headache now and growing.**

Comment: As a not on this issue, I haven't worked out what it was but I have fixed it by using cfg_broll_sr.tolist() to change the Pandas Series object into a Python list. This seems to work consistently with the for each loop. Possibly a bug in Pandas, more likely me not knowing what I am doing.

Comment: why don't u show the starting frame and what u want as an end result